# What is App.hiddenDivs in this jQuery code sample?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I was learning some performance related JQuery tips **[here](http://www.tech2grab.com/2012/10/download-jquery-performance-tips-cheat.html)**

[image]

Can you tell the meaning of App.hiddenDivs ?

Comment: It's literally just a means of storing your items in a global variable, instead of repeatedly calling $('div.hidden') - its contents will be readily available.

Comment: Could all the down-voters offer some advice to the OP on how the question could be improved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here `App` is a javascript object. You can create a javascript object like:

```
var App = new Object();
```

and set the `App` Object member like:

```
App.hiddenDivs = $('div.hidden');
```

Then you can access the object in you application like:

```
App.hiddenDivs.find('span');
```

It's like Caching jQuery Objects but at the Application level.

Answer (score 2):

`App` will be an object, and `hiddenDivs` will be a property on it;

By setting `$('div.hidden')` to it, it allows you to re-use the result (the jQuery object containing all `div.hidden` elements), rather than querying the DOM for it each time. This will result in a micro-speed-improvement.

Answer (score 2):

In general, `App.hiddenDivs` has absolutely nothing to do with jQuery. In this code, it just happens to be the place where a jQuery collection gets stored.

`App` is a JavaScript object of some sort (we don't know what it really is given the context, and it doesn't matter--it's just some imaginary object which is part of some imaginary code in which this example *could* live). It could have been something as simple as:

```
var App = {};
```

`hiddenDivs` is a property of that object which is defined to hold the return value of the jQuery code, `$('div.hidden')`.

That return value is a jQuery collection containing all `DIV`s in the DOM with the class of `hidden`. Further operations on such `DIV`s can then be run against that property, rather than re-seeking them in the DOM.

The page you link to, while probably holding some valuable advice, is poorly written. The author should provide a bit more background info on what he's writing about, and should have explained the expected level of knowledge his readers should have. Furthermore, he should offer code examples which build on each other as the explanations progress in order to provide some continuity for the more basic readers to follow.

Comment: u mean App is an inbuilt object like `this`? How can i access this...? I am trying to check it in Firefox Watch...it's saying `ReferenceError: App is not defined`

Comment: `App` is not a built in object. The code you are looking at is completely without context, and is assuming a level of knowledge JavaScript which would help you infer that somewhere else in some imaginary App in which this example might live, `App` is an object.